# Rendering camera problems

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, camera

I'm in a middle of rendering shot 2 of the veld for the animated short I'm creating and it keeps turning out like this. Feel free to comment if you have any suggestions.
[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: There can be several reasons why only the background is rendered. Upload your blend file through [this site](https://blend-exchange.com/) so respondents can review your file.

Comment: Maybe you've loaded a strip in the Viedo Sequencer, in that case it will play instead of your 3D scene, you need to go into the Output panel > Post-Processing > disable Sequencer